# Access JSON data from API

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a script to download images from an API, I have a set up a loop that is as follows:

```
    response = requests.get(url, params=query)
    json_data = json.dumps(response.text)
    pythonVal = json.loads(json.loads(json_data))
    print(pythonVal)
```

The print(pythonVal) returns:

```
 {
  "metadata": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "OK",
    "version": "v2.0"
  },
  "data": {
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "redactedLink"
    }
  },
  "id": "123456789",
  "_fixed": true
    ,
  "type": "IMAGE",
  "source": "social media",
  "source_id": "1234567890_1234567890",
  "original_source": "link",
  "caption": "caption",
  "video_url": null,
    "share_url": "link",
    "date_submitted": "2016-07-11T09:34:35+00:00",
  "date_published": "2016-09-11T16:30:26+00:00",
```

I keep getting an error that reads:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc4' in
position 527: ordinal not in range(128)
```

For the pythonVal variable, if I just have it set to `json.loads(json_data)`, it prints out the JSON response, but then when I try doing `pythonVal['data']` I get another error that reads:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Ultimately I'd like to be able to get data from it by doing something like

```
 pythonVal['data']['_embedded']['uploader']['username']
```

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Why doing `json.loads()` twice? Change:

```
json.loads(json.loads(json_data))
```

to:

```
json.loads(json_data)
```

and it should work.

Now since you are getting error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on doing `pythonVal['data']`, it means that the value of `pythonVal` is of `list` type and not `dict`. Instead do:

```
for item in pythonVal:
    print item
```

*Please also mention the sample JSON content with the question, if you want better help from others :)*

Comment: Hey thanks!  So I was doing json.loads(json_data) but as I mentioned I was getting that second error, if I do for item in pythonVal, it will just print each individual letter in from my response, which is not what I want, I am trying to get specific data from an API response `code`"status": "approved",
  "likes": 23,
  "request_id": null,`code` for example, If I wanted to get the status I'd want to be able to say pythonVal['status'] and have it return 'approved'

Comment: I order to let me better understand your problem, please could you update the question with the output of `print pythonVal ` and in that point me to the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following on top of your code. This works by overriding the native ascii encoding of Python to UTF-8.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

The second error is because you have already gotten the string, and you need integer indices to get the characters of the string.